# working with ssrs and i need to replace 0 with - and 1 with +

Tags: sql, string, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

working with SSRS and I need to replace 0 with - and 1 with + on a field, I tried a nested iif statement but I can not find what have I done wrong, it is not working

```
=IIf(Fields!partyAA.Value="0", iif (Fields!partyAA.Value = "1", "+"),"-")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
=IIf(Fields!partyAA.Value="0", "-", IIf (Fields!partyAA.Value = "1", "+", Fields!partyAA.Value))
```

This turns `0` to `-`, 1 to `+`, and leaves other values unchanged.